# How to lessen my TTFB(Time To First Byte) load time?

Tags: asp.net, performance, time, compilation, load

[image: Snapshot of my websites load times]

Is this what my load times are supposed to look like when the website is compiling on first hit?

I pre-compile on publish.
I set debug="false" in the webconfig file.
I don't use much in the way of CDN other than JQuery and google maps.
I am usually below 1MB in page size.

Comment: It could be, as long as it goes down on subsequent runs..

Comment: It does this after having not visited the site for a while or after I make new changes and publish them. After it compiles every page loads excellently. @bestinamir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to Google, your website’s TTFB should be 200 milliseconds or
> less.
>
> If your site is much slower than that, such as 500 milliseconds or
> more, it needs some work.
>
> Average Time to First Byte is 100-500ms. Google says to aim for 200ms

If you want to test your sites TTFB you can Enter your website URL at https://www.webpagetest.org/

This seems a little slow to me I would check your site for the following factors that can slow its TTFB speed:

1. High web traffic
2. Network problems
3. Dynamic content:
4. disk usage
5. disk speed
6. RAM usage
7. database setup
8. database speed
9. Server configuration:
10. PHP/ASP settings
11. database settings
12. shared server?

One great way to speed up your page load is by catching your dynamic pages.

> Caching your pages make the pages “pre-built,” with HTML ready to go
> as soon as a browser requests the pages.

Here are some ways to start using catche:

> 1. WordPress Plugins. Plugins such as WP Super Cache will help you cache
>    your dynamic pages. The plugin keeps tracks of when a "saved" dynamic
>    page should be renewed so that the freshest copy possible is served.
>    (See also: A Complete Guide To Using W3 Total Cache)
> 2. WordPress hosting
>    that caches automatically. WordPress hosting can give you caching
>    capabilities that improve your site’s TTFB.
> 3. Server Configuration. A common way to cache files -- but not dynamic content -- is to configure the .htaccess web file. (.htaccess is short
>    for hypertext access.) Beware that minor errors in this file can lead
>    to major problems; hiring a professional is advised.

As per https://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/16081-time-to-first-byte-seo.html which is a great resource.